# Timezones and DST handling in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, timezone, dst

I'm developing a `PHP/MySQL webapp` that tracks the status of some devices over time, receiving a series of snapshots sent by a Windows software through a `web service` (I have the control of the Windows software too, so I can apply modifications if necessary).

I have to face the timezones problem, since the Windows software often needs to pass the literal values of the timestamps (e.g. "2018-12-06 15:30:00") instead of `NOW()`, referring to its system time. The computer that runs it can be located in any state.

I've already migrated my MySQL data from the *datetime* format to *timestamp*, since the first one doesn't handle timezones, while *timestamp* - if I understood correctly - always stores the data related to GMT.

How can I pass this literal values from the Windows software making also note the reference timezone, to give MySQL a way to convert it correctly into GMT? I'm thinking about something like "2018-12-06 15:30:00+01:00" (which I have tried, but unsuccessfully).

In addition to this, I'd need a way to find out if DST is in effect or not from PHP, in order to decide how to offset the timestamp value. 
Is there a way to make this work?

EDIT: Regarding DST, I've found out that MySQL should have a way to know the time offset of a country compared to GMT in any time, but often the tables that deal with this are not populated on the MySQL server. Unfortunately it is also my case, and I cannot populate them manually because my hosting does not provide the access to them.

Comment: _“need a way to find out if DST is in effect or not from PHP”_ - that info would have to be send by the client, otherwise where do you expect to get it from?

Comment: Would be much easier to handle, if your Windows software could at least be convinced to send a unix timestamp, instead of a formatted date.

Comment: Best practice is to always store everything in UTC as your outlined approach suggests. Try to send UTC times from clients to server. Only deal with timezone when a date/time needs to be displayed in a client and apply the transition from UTC to the desired timezone at the time of display. PHP's `strtotime()` will correctly convert date/time strings that have time zone offset in them, e.g. your example of `2018-12-06 15:30:00+01:00` will be correctly converted to UTC timestamp. If you remove just the time zone offset part from that string, `strtotime()` will give a different result.

Comment: Ok thanks: I think that passing the timestamp in UNIX_TIMESTAMP format would be the best way to go.
In each individual instance of the webapp I will set a constant that contains the correct timezone to convert the data to, and then I will display the converted value.

Comment: This: "I have the control of the Windows software too..." - Then store UTC-based timestamps in the database and do all your time zone conversion in the Windows application, using whatever language/platform features of that application are available (ex, `TimeZoneInfo` if it's a .NET application, etc.).